# Install postgreSQL on Ubuntu dependency errors

Tags: postgresql, rails

I just installed a Bitnami Ruby Stack (Ubuntu, Rails, Rub, ...).
I would like to install postgreSQL.

I tried the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

But, I get this:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Package postgresql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
    This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
    is only available from another source
```

UPDATE1

I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
```

And got this:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    postgresql-9.1 : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not installable
     Depends: libpq5 (>= 9.1~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: postgresql-client-9.1 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: postgresql-common (>= 115~) but it is not installable
     Depends: ssl-cert but it is not installable
     E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

UPDATE2

This is the first time I have logged on via terminal from my iMac.  I guess I'm in a user directory.  What directory do I need to be in for the install to work?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running the server version of Ubuntu, you could try running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update the available packages, and then retrying the install with

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

If you are running the Desktop version of Ubuntu however, I would suggest installing postgresql via the Ubuntu Software Center, since this has always worked best for me.

Comment: Did this solve your problem?
Could you please tell me (and others) how you fixed it.

Comment: This did fix my issue.  I'm wondering if I was in the wrong directory?  When I first logged in I was in a user directory.  I cd .. till I got to the top and tried the above commands.  They worked!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already running Bitnami, you can install the [PostgreSQL Addon](http://bitnami.org/stack/postgresql)